# What is meta site actually used for?

Tags: support, help

This might seem stupid, but what actually the meta site does? The chat site is for general discussions that might be off-topic. But what is meta site used for?

So that next time when I ask a question, it's for sure that I am asking a questions that's related to the site.

**Edit:** I wasn't able to edit this, so here it goes. The answer I got was "The meta is a subdomain for a website which is entirely dedicated to the site itself!".

Comment: This might help you: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: I think you're asking this because you're trying to figure out why you are so heavily downvoted on your meta questions? If so, understand the meanings of upvotes and downvotes are different on meta compared to, for example, stackoverflow

Comment: I did read about the comparison, and yes, I do wanna know how to prevent from being downvoting. And to do that is the only way to use the correct way to use this site!

Comment: Please also see [help].

Comment: ಠ_ಠ's observation is, of course, true. Meta is different, and that includes voting. But knowing that doesn't really help you out very much. Perhaps you will find the answers to this question more useful: [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188)

Comment: Actually my question was not about how to get upvotes or downvotes, my question was how to use this site. What questions to cover?

Comment: The comments under the questions you've already asked seem to provide good guidance.  You should read them.

Comment: The answer below has some good material. Also the links provided are helpfull. Now I understand how to fairly use this meta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's become generally a site where people can point out errors on the site that allows them to point out errors.  :oP

There's discussion on rules, regulations, improvements, FAQs and other non-programming related conversation.  A quick look at the acceptable tags for this section should give you a good indication as to what goes on here.

Comment: I mean the meta is about the bugs or the stuff that users find somehow hard to handle, right?

Comment: That, and the functtionality of the main sites, among other things.  Not necessarily bugs, but there's plenty of discussion about bugs here.

Comment: Yes, I just read about it. The site covers about general discussions, bugs, stuff that needs to be added and etc!